# React - How to prevent parent re-render on prop change

Tags: reactjs

I am making a calculator using react.
Every time I press a number button, the whole application re-renders, instead of the `<Display />`.

To prevent it, I tried 2 different approaches for **App**, But neither of them worked.
[Here is the sandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tereshkova-2qyp6p)

Any help would be appreciated.

1. Put **clickHandler** inside of `useCallback()`

```
const App = () => {
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState("0");
  console.log("render");

  const clickHandler = useCallback(
    (val) => {
      if (val === "AC") {
        setScreen("");
        return;
      }
      screen === "0" ? setScreen(val) : setScreen(screen + val);
    },
    [screen]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="display">{screen}</div>
      <ButtonList clickHandler={clickHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

2. Put `Display component` inside of `React.memo`

```
const App = () => {
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState("0");
  console.log("render");

  const clickHandler = (val) => {
    if (val === "AC") {
      setScreen("");
      return;
    }
    screen === "0" ? setScreen(val) : setScreen(screen + val);
  };

  const displayComponent = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="display">{screen}</div>
        <ButtonList clickHandler={clickHandler} />
      </>
    );
  };

  const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(displayComponent);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MemoizedComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here's the ButtonList & Button component.

```
export const ButtonList = ({ clickHandler }) => {
  const arr = [...Array.from(Array(10).keys()).reverse(), "AC"];
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
      <div className="numbersWrapper">
        {arr.map((item) => (
          <Button
            key={item}
            clickHandler={clickHandler}
            value={item.toString()}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};



export const Button = ({ value, clickHandler }) => {
  return (
    <button
      name={value}
      onClick={() => {
        clickHandler(value); //where the clickEvent happens
      }}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please clarify why don't you need to re-render the `App` component since you only have code in there so it makes sense to re-render on every change. Btw `React.memo()` prevents re-renders only if the new `props` are the same as prev `props` which in your case doesn't even exist

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a component re-render,You would have to define the click handler in another component that you would like to re-render.

So do it like this:

```
const App = () => {
  console.log("render");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <childComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export const childComponent = () => {
const [screen, setScreen] = useState("0");
const clickHandler = (val) => {
        if (val === "AC") {
          setScreen("");
          return;
        }
        screen === "0" ? setScreen(val) : setScreen(screen + val);
      };
  return (
          <>
            <div className="display">{screen}</div>
            <ButtonList clickHandler={clickHandler} />
          </>
        );
}
```

This way you prevent a particular component from re-rendering. But note that if you update a state or do anything from which causes re-renders from the parent component, It would equally re-render the child component.